# How to post multipart/form-data?

Tags: jquery, rest, google-chrome-extension, multipartform-data, codenvy

I'm creating an extension that automates procedures within Codenvy by using the REST API they provide.  However, I'm having trouble with a multipart/form-data POST request.  Specically, creating a new factory.

This is my ajax/jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://codenvy.com/api/factory',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success:function(data) {
      callback();
    },
    error:function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

But I get a 409 error with the message:

> No factory URL information found in 'factoryURL' section of
>   multipart/form-data

I already posted on Codenvy forums, but the only useful thing I got was a curl command

> POST http://domain.com/api/factory?token=$token -H 'Content-Type:
>   multipart/form-data' -F
>   'factoryUrl={$JSONofFactoryConfig}'

[rfc2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) says something about a name field, but I have no idea how to convert the curl name field into an ajax request.

How should I go about adding this "factoryUrl" field to my POST request?

Comment: What is the value of `formData`?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this.
I knew that I was missing the factoryUrl portion in my payload, I just didn't know how to put it in my payload.
The following code did the job:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('factoryUrl', JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
// Send ajax post request
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing factoryUrl in your payload. It should be:

```
factoryUrl={json_with_project_config}
```